# Javascript for loop not running correctly

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, canvas, kineticjs

I have an array full of code that needs to be executed. It's part of a project using [kinetic.js](http://kineticjs.com/) for HTML5 canvas.

I run a `for loop` to go through this array and use `eval()` to execute the code from the array. The array is called `tiles` and one part may look like this:

```
context.fillStyle="rgb(255,255,255)";
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(256,197);
context.lineTo(177,241);
context.bezierCurveTo(172,237,167,232,162,228);
context.fill();
```

Now I have my for loop combined with the normal kinetic code to go through the array, execute the code and create shapes on my canvas. For example:

```
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
for (var i=0 ;i<5; i++) {
  var tile = new Kinetic.Shape({
    sceneFunc: function(context){ eval(tiles[i]); }
  });
  layer.add(tile);
}
stage.add(layer);
```

But this only adds one of the array items!! What the hell is going on? This is super confusing because if I write out the for loop, it works. Like this:

```
var tile = new Kinetic.Shape({
  sceneFunc: function(context){ eval(tiles[0]); }
});
layer.add(tile);

var tile = new Kinetic.Shape({
  sceneFunc: function(context){ eval(tiles[1]); }
});
layer.add(tile);

var tile = new Kinetic.Shape({
  sceneFunc: function(context){ eval(tiles[2]); }
});
layer.add(tile);

etc...
```

Comment: and [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/218196).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closure:

```
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
for (var i=0 ;i<5; i++) {
  (function(num) {
     var tile = new Kinetic.Shape({
       sceneFunc: function(context){ eval(tiles[num]); }
     });
     layer.add(tile);
  }(i));
}
```

Comment: Are you saying the closure is the problem or the solution?

Comment: This works!! Why? I've never had to do this in a for loop before. Is there a reason?

Comment: @cooper: I assume you already had a look at the other questions and got an explanation?